# What's the difference between these two inheritance ways in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, ember.js, coffeescript

Today I wasted hours in a weird bug while developing ember

I confidently ignored the Ember extend way

```
App.SomeModel = DS.Model.extend()
```

and somehow turned into my prefer way

```
class App.SomeModel extends DS.Model()
```

My second way just didn't work. So I want to know what's the difference between these two and why the second way didn't work in Ember(Cuz' both ways work in Backbone)

Comment: If we're talking about JavaScript the second way won't work in any framework; it's just a syntax error. And I think your first sample is wrong to; it's probably supposed to be `DS.Model.extend()` or something.

Comment: @Pointy my bad, should have stated im using coffeescript, i will edit it

Comment: OK, well the Coffeescript "extends" thing makes its own assumptions about how things work, and (I suppose) that's OK in Backbone. Apparently the Ember "extends()" mechanism does its own important things behind the scenes, and Coffeescript has no clue about what those things are.

Comment: @Pointy i see... gotta take a look on their source code

Comment: Don't you mean `class App.SomeModel extends DS.Model`? CoffeeScript classes are functions so you can legally say `DS.Model()` but that's probably not what you want to do.

Comment: http://codebrief.com/2012/08/hacking-the-coffeescript-compiler/ discusses the mismatch between the Coffeescript 'classes' and the Ember object model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
App.SomeModel = DS.Model.extend()
```

This calls Ember.js's own Object extend method, which adds observers, reopens a class and so on.

```
class App.SomeModel extends DS.Model()
```

Doesn't rely on a framework, In plain javascript, It's assigning "Somemodel" the properties of the "DS.Model()" object. It's not expected to work inside the framework for extending Ember.Object's

Answer (score 0):

Look at EmberScript

http://emberscript.com/

The key difference is that the `Class` and `extends` compile directly to the `Ember` equivalents, rather than trying to make the Coffeescript ideas fit with Ember.

```
class SomeModel extends Ember.Object
```

becomes

```
var SomeModel;
var get$ = Ember.get;
var set$ = Ember.set;
SomeModel = Ember.Object.extend();
```